# What happened to Betty Ross?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk-2008

Betty Ross was in the 2008 Hulk film but not in other MCU films.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bruce decided that he couldn't risk Betty's life being around her when he might, at any moment turn into a ravening beast (or worse, attract the attention of the military by his mere presence).

> Then Bruce meditated. Every day he got a little better at keeping the beast inside. But he wouldn’t be able to hold it in forever. That wouldn’t matter as long as he could control it… and where he had once meditated to hold the monster in, now Bruce was learning how to use meditation to bring the change into the Hulk when he wanted it. On his terms.
>   He practiced. He kept practicing.
>   **One of these days, when he had it right, he would find Betty again.**
>
> <sub><sup>[The Incredible hulk: Official Novelisation](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/The_Incredible_Hulk_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: She might be making a return in Infinity War, according to unconfirmed rumours; http://wegotthiscovered.com/movies/avengers-infinity-war-liv-tyler/

Comment: Luckily, Hulk wasn't in Captain America: Civil War, so fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Valorum Now that the film is out, we know she did not return for Infinity War

Comment: @StevenVascellaro - Sure, but she might be in future films. I'll update it if she turns up in Avengers 4